# VueJS: How do you provide a context variable to @change handler?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a `select` widget inside a loop:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    <select @change="handleChange">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

When handleChange is triggered, I want to get following pieces of information:

1. `index` of the parent loop
2. `value` of the selected option

Above code only gives me #2. How do I get #1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways that you can do this:

## Solution 1: Bind `index` to an arbitrary HTML5 `data-` attribute

This approach involves using `:data-index="index"` on your select element, and then using the `e.target.dataset.index` to retrieve the bound `index` of the element

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet']
  },
  methods: {
    handleChange(e) {
      console.log(e.target.value, e.target.dataset.index);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    <select @change="handleChange" :data-index="index">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, you can store the `index` as any other arbitrarily-named `data-` attribute, e.g. `<select @change="handleChange" :data-abc="index">` and then simply accessing it in your JS using `e.target.dataset.abc`.

---

## Solution 2: Pass `index` as an argument to the `@click` callback

This method involves passing `$event` and `index` as parameters to your `handleChange` callback. [The `$event` variable in VueJS allows you to pass the original JS event to the handler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet']
  },
  methods: {
    handleChange(e, idx) {
      console.log(e.target.value, idx);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    <select @change="handleChange($event, index)">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

for parent loop index,

```
<select @change="handleChange(index)">
```

for value of selected option, use **v-model** for two way binding